# Calculating Uncertainty in simple linear and by calculator

Tags: calculator

How do you measure the uncertainty of m and c in y=mx+c by regression formulas in a calculator from a set of given data points (x,y)? I know the actual statistical formula, but that looks too cumbersome to apply. I am using a Casio FX-991ES Plus.